# Monitoring AWS Kinesis stream on the shell console

Tags: aws-cli

I am sending data stream to AWS kinesis service and want to check if the kinesis received the data. What I expect is real-time output on shell console like redis does:
[image]

Wonder if AWS CLI supports features like that.